# Is there any possibility to make a try catch function as an infix function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an infix function to my project to check the result of a try catch function.

I saw a solution out there but is passing the block as parameter and running that block inside the tryOrNull function like that.

```
fun <T : Any> tryOrNull(body: () -> T?): T? {
//the body returns T? so that you can give up the work by returning null
return try {
body()
} catch (e: Exception) {
e.printStackTrace()
null
}
```

}

and using like that

```
fun parse(): MyData? {
return tryOrNull { parse1() }
?: tryOrNull { parse2() }
?: tryOrNull { parse3() }
```

}

this info I saw [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/a-tryornull-function/6974)

But I would like to know if there is a different way to this something like that

```
fun parse(): MyData? {
return parse().tryOrNull() ?: false
}
```

I would like to create an infix or extension function but I don't know how to manage at all. Thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you suggested (`parse().tryOrNull()`) would be impossible because `parse()` would be called and return a result before it reached `tryOrNull()`.

However,

```
::parse.tryOrNull()
```

or

```
{ parse() }.tryOrNull()
```

are possible if you write your utility function like this:

```
inline fun <T> (() -> T).tryOrNull(): T? = runCatching(this)
    .also { it.exceptionOrNull()?.printStackTrace() }
    .getOrNull()
```

But I think the original syntax you showed is clearer. It makes more semantic sense to see the thing you are calling wrapped in the `tryOrNull` call instead of tacking `tryOrNull` on like an afterthought.